# How does "evil/ponera" in 1 John 3:12 compare with "evil/kakon" in Romans 12:17?

Tags: word-choice

1 John 3:12  "..And why did he murder him? Because his own deeds were evil [ponera] and his brother's righteous". ESV.

Romans 12:17 "Repay no one evil [kakon] for evil, but give thought to do what is honourable in the sight of all". ESV.

These evils have things in common, e.g. they are both related to deeds between humans.

What differences might there be between them in view of the different Greek words used?

Comment: Could this not be solved simply by consulting a good lexicon?

Comment: @Dottard Why does someone give back evil for evil? Is it because they despair of doing good or that they positively wish harm? I can't see for example where Thayer touches on this?

Answer (score 1):

Matthew 7:17
English Standard Version

> So, every healthy tree bears good fruit, but the diseased tree bears **bad** [G4190] fruit.

1 John 3:12

> We should not be like Cain, who was of the **evil** [G4190] one and murdered his brother. And why did he murder him? Because his own deeds were **evil** [G4190] and his brother’s righteous.

https://biblehub.com/greek/4190.htm
Strong's Exhaustive Concordance

> From a derivative of **ponos** [G4190]; **hurtful**, i.e. Evil (properly, in effect or influence, and thus differing from **kakos**  [G2556], which refers rather to essential **character**

https://biblehub.com/greek/2556.htm
HELPS Word-studies

> 2556 **kakós** (an adjective, and the root of 2549 /kakía, "**inner** malice") – properly, inwardly foul, rotten (poisoned); (figuratively) inner malice flowing out of a morally-rotten character (= the "rot is already in the wood").

Apparently, John focused on outward evil things; Cain did a bad/evil deed. Paul's focus was deeper: inward evil heart/character.

Romans 12:

> 9
> Let love be genuine. Abhor what is evil [G4190]; hold fast to what is good.

This is the same Greek outward-evil used by John. Eight verses later, Paul switched to the inward-evil:

> 17 Repay no one evil for **evil** [G2556], but give thought to do what is honorable in the sight of all.

> 21 Do not be overcome by **evil** [G2556], but overcome **evil** [G2556] with good.

The outward-inward distinction that I've made here is a bit of over-simplification. As usual, in practice, there are some overlapping usages of these two Greek words.

Why does someone give back evil for evil? Is it because they despair of doing good or that they positively wish harm?

According to Paul's usage of G2556 (inward evil), it is because they positively wish harm from their evil hearts.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to such questions is almost always provided by W E Vine, Expository Dictionary of NT Words which is available in several places online.  The article on "Evil" is most instructive here and is reproduced in the appendix below.

The essence of that material can be summarized as:

> **kakos** stands for "whatever is evil in character, base," in distinction
> (wherever the distinction is observable) from **poneros** (see No. 2),
> which indicates "what is evil in influence and effect, malignant."
> Kakos is the wider term and often covers the meaning of poneros.

In Rom 12:17 we find Paul saying: "Do not repay anyone evil for evil." This anticipates the advice in V19 - *Do not avenge yourselves, beloved, but leave room for God’s wrath. For it is written: “Vengeance is Mine; I will repay, says the Lord.”*

Thus, prepaying "evil for evil" appears to be some kind of revenge or vengeance which Christian are told NOT to do.

**APPENDIX - extract from W E Vine, Expository Dictionary**

> **1: κακός** (Strong's #2556 — Adjective — kakos — kak-os' )
>
> stands for "whatever is evil in character, base," in distinction
> (wherever the distinction is observable) from poneros (see No. 2),
> which indicates "what is evil in influence and effect, malignant."
> Kakos is the wider term and often covers the meaning of poneros. Kakos
> is antithetic to kalos, "fair, advisable, good in character," and to
> agathos, "beneficial, useful, good in act;" hence it denotes what is
> useless, incapable, bad; poneros is essentially antithetic to
> chrestos, "kind, gracious, serviceable;" hence it denotes what is
> destructive, injurious, evil. As evidence that poneros and kakos have
> much in common, though still not interchangeable, each is used of
> thoughts, cp. Matthew 15:19 with Mark 7:21; of speech, Matthew 5:11
> with 1 Peter 3:10; of actions, 2 Timothy 4:18 with 1 Thessalonians
> 5:15; of man, Matthew 18:32 with Matthew 24:48 .
>
> The use of kakos may be broadly divided as follows: (a) of what is
> morally or ethically "evil," whether of persons, e.g., Matthew 21:41;
> 24:48; Philippians 3:2; Revelation 2:2 , or qualities, emotions,
> passions, deeds, e.g., Mark 7:21; John 18:23,30; Romans 1:30; 3:8;
> 7:19,21; 13:4; 14:20; 16:19; 1 Corinthians 13:5; 2 Corinthians 13:7; 1
> Thessalonians 5:15; 1 Timothy 6:10; 2 Timothy 4:14; 1 Peter 3:9,12;
> (b) of what is injurious, destructive, baneful, pernicious, e.g., Luke
> 16:25; Acts 16:28; 28:5; Titus 1:12; James 3:8; Revelation 16:2 ,
> where kakos and poneros come in that order, "noisome and grievous."
> See B, No. 3. For compounds of kakos, see below.
>
> **2: πονηρός** (Strong's #4190 — Adjective — poneros — pon-ay-ros' )
>
> akin to ponos, "labor, toil," denotes "evil that causes labor, pain,
> sorrow, malignant evil" (see No. 1); it is used (a) with the meaning
> bad, worthless, in the physical sense, Matthew 7:17,18; in the moral
> or ethical sense, "evil," wicked; of persons, e.g., Matthew 7:11; Luke
> 6:45; Acts 17:5; 2 Thessalonians 3:2; 2 Timothy 3:13; of "evil"
> spirits, e.g., Matthew 12:45; Luke 7:21; Acts 19:12,13,15,16; of a
> generation, Matthew 12:39,45; 16:4; Luke 11:29; of things, e.g.,
> Matthew 5:11; 6:23; 20:15; Mark 7:22; Luke 11:34; John 3:19; 7:7; Acts
> 18:14; Galatians 1:4; Colossians 1:21; 1 Timothy 6:4; 2 Timothy 4:18;
> Hebrews 3:12; 10:22; James 2:4; 4:16; 1 John 3:12; 2 John 1:11; 3 John
> 1:10; (b) with the meaning toilsome, painful, Ephesians 5:16; 6:13;
> Revelation 16:2 . Cp. poneria, "iniquity, wickedness." For its use as
> a noun see B, No. 2.

Answer (score 1):

κακὸν ἀντὶ κακοῦ leaves the impression that Paul was thinking about Hebrew scriptures with the word
רָ֑ע
such as in the verse:

```
        Do not say, “I will repay evil”; 
  wait for the LORD, and he will deliver you. 
                        (Prov 20:22, ESV)
```

Both the Hebrew and Greek words mean bad, which includes the idea of evil as these words often mean in scripture.  Note the following Jewish translation to English.

> And from the ground the LORD God caused to grow every tree that was pleasing to the sight and good for food, with the tree of life in the middle of the garden, and the tree of knowledge of **good and bad**.
> (Gen. 2:9, JPS Tanakh)

In 1 John 3:12  ἐκ τοῦ πονηροῦ means *wicked, evil*.  While the meaning of these two words can be different, they are nearly synonyms in these two verses.

> κακός, ή, όν; κακῶς: pertaining to being bad, with the implication of harmful and damaging—‘bad, evil, harmful, harshly.’
> --
> Louw, J. P., & Nida, E. A. (1996). Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament: based on semantic domains (electronic ed. of the 2nd edition., Vol. 1, p. 753). New York: United Bible Societies.

> πονηρός, ά, όν: pertaining to being morally corrupt and evil—‘immoral, evil, wicked.’
> --
> Louw, J. P., & Nida, E. A. (1996). Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament: based on semantic domains (electronic ed. of the 2nd edition., Vol. 1, p. 753). New York: United Bible Societies.